# Автоматическое снятие роли mute(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, member

Существует банальный код для выдачи Mute:

```
    async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason = "Без причины"):
    timeID = time * 60
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Мут", color=0xc25151, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор:',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    
    await asyncio.sleep(timeID)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Параметры {ctx.author.id}, {member.id}, {time}, "{reason}", {ctx.guild.id}, "{ctx.guild.name}", "{datetime.datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)} я сохраняю в sqlite3.

В коде, который предоставлен выше, это не прописано, но данные есть.

Так вот суть проблемы.
Данные сохраняются и код работает, но есть один фактор. При перезапуске бота, информация слетает, то есть если у человека была роль Muted(Её выдал модератор), то бот её просто не снимет.
Возможно ли через sqlite3, чтобы бот при запуске проверял информацию, и если дата, когда мут должен быть снят, бот автоматически его снимал. Желательно всё это делать через:
*@bot.event*

**Буду очень благодарен за помощь.**

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите реализовать, то Вам необходимо для начала создать цикл. Для этого можно использовать `tasks.loop`:

```
from discord.ext import tasks
```

Далее создадим сам цикл:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=0) #Вместо 0 указываем время в секундах, через которое он будет повторяться.
async def mutecheck():
```

Далее в этом цикле мы уже и достаем данные из базы данных и проверяем, что-то подобное:

```
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    #возьмём для примера день. 

    time = int(now.strftime("%d"))
    if time == #дата из бд:
```

Сам цикл необходимо запустить с помощью `on_ready`:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    mutecheck.start()
```

Comment: Допустим есть время(когда наказание было выдано): 2022-12-10 21:57:00(Datemuted), и время, на сколько он был выдан 40(Dateclose). Как это всё организовать? Также как всё это организовать с подключением к бд, допустим - conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db') 
        cur = conn.cursor() и т.д.

Comment: Хм.. ну можно попробовать сделать по-другому. Подождите не много.

Comment: @shakspeare оставил ответ ещё один в кратце. додумывайте сами т.к. я не собираюсь писать код за Вас. ищите информацию в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

Мне пришла в голову ещё одна идея. Можно попробовать сделать фактически такой же процесс, только не много по-другому.

Предположим вы выдали мут таким образом: `.mute @user 10м`. Теперь Вам необходимо занести 10 минут в базу данных, но при этом это должно быть значение в секундах. Для этого конвертируем:

```
        try:
            t = int(time)
        except:
            convertTimeList = {'с':1, 'м':60, 'ч':3600, 'д':86400, 'С':1, 'М':60, 'Ч':3600, 'Д':86400}
            t = int(time[:-1]) * convertTimeList[time[-1]]
```

Далее заносим полученное значение в бд.

Создаем цикл:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=60) #данные будут обновляться каждые 60 секунд.
async def mutecheck():
    # for test in ..... - достаем из бд наше время мута.
    if test[0] == 60:
        #обновляем бд и ставим значение 0 и забираем мут у пользователя.
    if test[0] > 0:
        #обновляем бд и забираем 60 секунд из нашей переменной.
```

Конечно это всё расписано в кратце. На самом деле здесь довольно большой код получится.